# In Java is there a way to name an ArrayList inside the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, nested

When I've needed a way of easily identifying an ArrayList inside an ArrayList, I would just put an identifier in the 0 index, then print out all the zero indexes with a loop.
Now I'm wondering if there is a way to make the nested ArrayLists have names.

for example:

```
ListOfLists.add( new ArrayList<String>() );
ListOfLists.get(ListOfLists.size() -1).add("someIdentifierHumansCanRead");
```

would there be some way to make `ListOfLists.add(new ArrayList<String>())` be 
`ListOfLists.add(ArrayList someIdentifierHumansCanRead = new ArrayList<String>)`?

Or would this just be completely absurd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your own `ArrayList` class and define an identifier property for it:

```
class NamedList<T> extends ArrayList 
{
    private String name;

    public NamedList(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Getters/Setters and other stuff for identifier, etc.
}

ArrayList<NamedList<String>> superList = new ArrayList<NamedList<String>>();
superList.add(new NamedList<String>("babangida"));
```

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez I'd say "see mine" :-) To add unrelated functionality, you should use composition, not inherit directly from ArrayList. What if you now need 2 separate lists in the structure? It also hides implementation details, such as using an ArrayList or a LinkedList. See the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Answer (score 4):

You are speaking of map where all the array lists are  keyed by strings - but you will lose iteration order.  Alternatively you can store keys in array list  and array lists in maps.

Comment: *"you will lose iteration order"* => it depends on the map implementation. `LinkedHashMap` preserves insertion order for example.

Comment: @assylias +1, I was just going to suggest `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez My main comment is that retrieving a `NamedList` by name with your approach will be an O(n) operation and will require looping over all the lists, whereas with the Map approach, it becomes an O(1) operation.

Comment: @assylias but what if the user wants to keep 2 lists with the same name? e.g. dogs,cats,cats,horses,cats. the op doesn't have to merge these "cats" lists? in that case a map will fail. am i wrong?

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez Yes you are right, the Map approach assumes that the names are unique identifiers, which might not be the case - the question is farily vague to be honest. Or he could store the lists in a `Map<String, List<List<...>>>`, where each name points to all the lists with that name.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to "name" your ArrayList, then you really want to create a meaningful data structure instead of using hacks. This is OO programming, after all:

```
public void MyNamedBean {
    private String name;
    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public MyNamedBean(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // If you don't need to change the name, make the field
    // final and remove this method.
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // It should have a more meaningful name.
    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Update, based on my comments on another answer: it's an OO design issue. If it's a list with a name, it's not *just* a list, which means you shouldn't directly extend a List implementation, but instead create a meaningful class. What if you need at some point a second list, or another "name" (a human-readable label, for example)? You can read on the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) about when to use inheritance and when to use composition. See also [Prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

If you meant references you cant try this

```
ArrayList someIdentifierHumansCanRead = new ArrayList<String>();
ListOfLists.add(someIdentifierHumansCanRead)
```

Or you can use a `Map<String,List<String>>` if you want to retrieve the arraylist using an identifier.

```
map.put("id",new ArrayList<String>());
```

The map can be a HashMap / LinkedHashMap / TreeMap etc. The iteration order will depend on the chosen implementation.

Comment: I'll have to look into this. I'm not sure I've ever tried to implement a map in Java.

Comment: You don't have to implement a Map. Jave provides one for you. Try new HashMap<String,List<String>>();